# No xmpp Client is able to connect to Openfire Server on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openfire

On an aws ec2 Instance Ubuntu 14.04 , I have setup openfire  using [This Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openfire-xmpp-server-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps) .

This just a test server so no worries there  , **the firewall is off** , the **security group of aws allows all traffic** from all IP and I checked via telnet **ports are reachable** , I can login to admin Also I  set the server public ip as servers IP/Domain when I setup the server for first time to create admin account.

Now my issue is Created a user but when i use any xmpp client like spark or Instandbird or any common xmpp app on iphone or andorid it can not connect.

**Public Dns : ec2-52-45-76-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com**

**public ip : 52.45.76.95**

For any one to test I created users like :

Username : vishal
password is Vrin@1234

Username :kush
password is 123

If any one wants admin credentials you can ask I can provide as I am just testing this one blank server.

Can any one know the reason why it is not connecting ?

Btw the server screen[image]

Comment: I just checked the provided details, and i am able to successfully login using vishal user. Don't know how you are trying to connect. It's working fine.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal - Same issue I have too, can you please elaborate more or put your code here for connection?

Comment: @iPatel - I simply logged-in from desktop client (Spark) using the provided details by Kush. I haven't wrote any code as Kush stated he is not able to login using a desktop client. If you are unable to perform XMPP Login with code, can you try with a desktop client, just to make sure that server is properly running.

Comment: @Shoaib 
Thanks for Replying
Hello, It Would be appreciated if you shared a Screenshot of spark client what settings you used ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the login using Spark and it's working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, I also connected in "Aduim" too.

Comment: Thanks I think there is something wrong with my Laptop so I was not able to connect , I Disabled Firewall Also