# Server field in spark client for openfire xmpp

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have installed Openfire xmpp server on my pc, but for testing chat in spark client, I can't figure what to fill in SERVER field in spark login window
I tried

```
 http://localhost:9090/
```

but it says wrong username or password every time.

Here is the openfirepanel:

[image]

The links here are not working, but I can access the panel at

```
 http://127.0.0.1:9090/index.jsp
```

[image]

And this is the spark dialog:
I have created a user with username and pass as 'bob','bob'
I have tried entering the server as 'nikhilverma1395','localhost', none is working.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: did you register any user? admin works?

Comment: I can access the admin panel with the admin credentials, and yes I have created two different users to test chat.

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: Do you have a proxy?

Comment: No, I don't use a proxy

Comment: nikhilverma1395 must works, "bob" figures in users list (admin panel?)

Comment: and Yes I have user 'bob' in UserGroups/User Summary. No, It is not working, It says wrong username or password and btw the links in Openfire panel   http://nikhilverma1395:9090/ and 9091 are not opening in my browser (it says can't be reached).

Comment: Seems to be a proxy issue, but you said you don't use proxy. I really have no idea, sorry! When I had this problem I just added my equivalent of nikhilverma1395 in proxy exceptions....

Comment: How did you add it in proxy excep. ?

Comment: https://www.stlouis-mo.gov/government/departments/information-technology/web-development/web-tutorials/browsers/add-exception-proxy-settings.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem in my Windows 10, I dual booted Ubuntu and did the same procedure with Certificate Authorization disabled in Spark and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In server field you need to provide the domain of Openfire server. For local machine, "localhost", "127.0.0.1" will work.

Have a look at this answer where Openfire server was hosted on Amazon and I entered it's url in server field.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506528/6041485

Comment: Can you telnet port 5222 on localhost?

Comment: I didn't get that ?

Comment: For openfire admin, 9090 port is used, and for XMPP connection 5222 port is used. As you are unable to perform XMPP Login from Spark, so just to make sure that Openfire is listening on 5222 port, you should try to telnet port 5222 from terminal/command prompt. If you are on windows, you might have to enable telnet from Turn Windows features on or off

Answer (score 0):

**may this help you**

please set nikhilverma1395 as a your server name.

Comment: No, It is not working, It says wrong username or password and btw the links in Openfire panel   http://nikhilverma1395:9090/ and 9091 are not opening in my browser (it says can't be reached).

Comment: your server and hostname is different then try Google that is your Hostname

Comment: can u try with Hostname ? bcoz right now i am working on android chat app with xmpp and my side its working